# Can select read index page while modify this page in innodb?

Tags: mysql, innodb

When mysql innodb insert or update secondary index page , will at the same time this index page can searched by `select` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, that's what the change buffer is for. It caches changes to secondary indexes. When data is read via an index and (parts of) the index is in the change buffer, it's read from there. The changes are written to disk periodically.

> The change buffer is a special data structure that caches changes to secondary index pages when affected pages are not in the buffer pool. The buffered changes, which may result from INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations (DML), are merged later when the pages are loaded into the buffer pool by other read operations.
>   ...
>   Periodically, the purge operation that runs when the system is mostly idle, or during a slow shutdown, writes the updated index pages to disk.

Read about it in more detail [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-insert-buffering.html).

Also creating/dropping/changing an index is possible while selects/insert/updates/deletes can be performed at the same time with online DDL (at least with MySQL >= 5.6).

Read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html).

Comment: Thanks . I see . But  when `change buffer are merged later when the pages` ,  the thread should lock the page , so this time can block the index query which hit this page ?

Comment: Not really. It is written to disk what is in the buffer pool. What's reading is reading from the buffer pool. So there's no lock contention there.

Comment: Not only `written to disk` , it need merge to exist page , so  I think it need first read this page to buffer pool then lock this page, finally write to disk . Does it right ?  So what's the problem is : at some time the `insert or update` data must write to the b+tree node , so it need lock some page to update , and at this time , was this page can be readed ?

Comment: No, it works this way: When an insert comes along but the data is not yet in buffer pool, the data is simply written to the transaction log and the changes to the index are written to the change buffer. When the data needs to be read, it is loaded in the buffer pool. When the data is in the buffer pool it of course also is noted where the data was read from (from which page). When the data changes, it is marked as dirty in the buffer pool and the change statement is written to the transaction log. Every once in a while the dirty pages in the buffer pool are flushed to disk (the tablespace). ..

Comment: The pages that need to be flushed do not need to be read again. They are already in the buffer pool. The change buffer also writes to pages in the index (that's not the same as the pages for the actual data) every once in a while, when the server is relatively idle. But there does not need to be any locking. The threads handle this themselves and most likely aren't even writing to the same pages.

Comment: Also I'm a little curious, why you think you need to know that. You don't have to worry about such things at all. I've never experienced any trouble with this and threads don't even have a thread state that regards to writing to indexes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/general-thread-states.html